# Extjs4 array.push issue

Tags: arrays, extjs4, push

I am working in extjs4. I have response from server side as =

```
0 Object { id=1, field={...}, formType=2, more...}
1 Object { id=2, field={...}, formType=2, more...}
2 Object { id=5, field={...}, formType=2, more...}
3 Object { id=8, field={...}, formType=2, more...}
```

i want to add these above records into array. So i have created code as=

```
fieldArray =new array();
Ext.Array.forEach(response, function(element) {
  fieldArray.push(element);
}
```

But at end of processing,this fieldArray is showing only one record with id=1. So how to add these all above elements into array in extjs4

Comment: You assume in your code that response is an array (you're using `forEach`). But this is probably not the case.

Comment: Actually sir i am creating dynamic fields with xtype as 'displayField'.So for these newly crested fields i am assighning values from above response. And finally adding those fields into array. But my fieldArray is showing only one field in it,not all fields

Comment: So what is `console.log(response)` telling ? Is the really an array? Or what is it ?

Comment: @user1722857 have you declared "var fieldArray" or just "fieldArray" ?